# Creating a pom.xml file in gradle with scope other than runtime

Tags: java, maven, gradle, pom.xml

I'm creating a pom file for a jar that I"m uploading to Artifactory. I do this by running this task to create the pom. The pom is well formed and I can publish the jar. However, the library's dependences are set to the runtime scope. I want it set so that when someone pulls my package, they also get the dependencies without having to include the explicitly.

```
task createPom  {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId 'my.cool.lib'
            artifactId project.name
            version project.version
            inceptionYear '2020'
        }
    }.writeTo("pom.xml")
}
```

Creates a dependencies tag:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.flatbuffers</groupId>
      <artifactId>flatbuffers-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.12.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I get `runtime` scope if my library's dependencies use `implementation` as the modifier. If I use `compile`, which is deprecated in current gradle versions, then the runtime is set to `compile`. How can I use `implementation`, but set the scope in the `pom.xml` to something other than `runtime`?

I've seen some questions on SO about altering the publish task which builds the POM, but I need to create the pom separately.

Comment: What is the reason you don't want users of your library to declare the dependencies? Usually, every dependency that is used in source code should be declared. One should no use transitive dependencies in your source code.

Comment: that's not how dependencies work from my experience. I guess I"m thinking of things like spring boot which have all the dependencies in there. In this case, I have a library that depends on a specific version of google flatbuffers and I want to make sure the right version of that lib is included.

Comment: So should the user of your library also directly access classes from google flatbuffers?

Comment: If your library uses a dependency which is an implementation specific detail that users of your library should not worry about, use the `implementation` configuration and leave them in the `runtime` scope. This is generally considered best practice. If the dependency is something you like to expose to the consumers, for instance because you use classes from it in public APIs, use the `api` configuration from the `java-library` plugin and the scope will change accordingly. If you look at the Spring Boot starters, you will also notice that they use the `api` configuration for their dependencies.

Comment: Well, I don't want to expose hte library's dependency to the consumers. I mostly just wanted to avoid having a consumer specify the dependency. It's needed at runtime, but doesn't need to be exposed.

Comment: Yes, but why change the scope then? If it is `runtime`, the customer will get it automatically as transitive dependency.

Comment: @JFMeier that didn't seem to be the case when I did a gradle build.

Comment: That sounds strange. In maven this is certainly the case.