# Gradle 6.8 implementation scope mapped to runtime in the Maven pom.xml. Shouldn't it be compile?

Tags: gradle, gradle-dependencies

In this Gradle 6.8 build.gradle there are a bunch of compile dependencies.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}


dependencies {
    compile "xxx:yyy.1.0.0"
}
```

With `gradle install` the generated pom looks as expected:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xxx</groupId>
      <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Since compile is deprecated I changed it to implementation:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "xxx:yyy.1.0.0"
}
```

However now the `gradle install` command translates it as as runtime dep:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xxx</groupId>
      <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The [doc](https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.1/userguide/building_java_projects.html) states:

> implementation (supersedes compile) — used for compilation and runtime

How come it isn't considered compile?

Comment: I'm wondering this too. I've been unable to find an answer on Google.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62415347/714112

Comment: Looks like it's answered here (though I don't yet understand it): https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-maven-publish-plugin/issues/66